# spark_apply() of spaklyr does not work with tm library

Tags: text-mining, tm, sparklyr

I am trying to use 'tm' library functionalities with spark_apply() function of sparklyr.

I have created a sparkdataframe named as **train** from a text file:

**train details:**

Source: table [?? x 1]

Database: spark_connection

line

1 Thank you. To Mama Gra�a Machel,

2 "On Tuesday, xyz abc "

Then I have defined my customised function as:

```
myfunction<-function(data){
test<-tm::Corpus(VectorSource(data))
test<-Corpus(VectorSource(test))
test<-tm_map(test,content_transformer(stripWhitespace))
dtm<-DocumentTermMatrix(test)
dtm<-as.matrix(dtm)
dtm<-as.data.frame(dtm)
return(dtm)
}
```

But when I am running the spark_apply function as follows:

`spark_apply(train,myfunction)` , it is throwing the below error ,

**Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
cannot open file 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpIzVe9J\file53c76462a6c_spark.log': Permission denied**

I have verified the cmd files in spark bin ,and I have all the required permissions as it is my own local machine.

Just to cross verify I ran the below code and it works fine:

```
myfunction1<-function(data){
test<-tm::MC_tokenizer(data)
}
spark_apply(train,myfunction1)
```

**Result**:

```
Source: table<sparklyr_tmp_53c119568d> [?? x 1]
Database: spark_connection
line
1 Thank
2 you
3 To
4 Mama
5 Gra
6 a
7 Machel
```

Note:

```
spark_version(spark_conn)
[1] ‘2.3.0’
packageVersion('sparklyr')
[1] ‘0.8.4’
```

Would be great if anyone can look into this issue .

Comment: I had a similar problem (see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56466994/spark-apply-error-specifying-column-names/56555317?noredirect=1#comment99720569_56555317), which I think likely causes your problem too. I would try to add line by line to your function, to see which part(s) cause the issue.